# What is the practical way write recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I saw many methods to write Recyclerview. But I do not know what is the best practice way  in terms of performance.

I have two methods to write a Recyclerview, are they the same or is there in difference?

First method is to write it in separate Adapter class

**Adapter.java**

```
public class Adapter  extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.MyViewHolder> {

@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder myViewHolder, int i) {

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 0;
}

class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
    }
}
}
```

Second method is to write it like this inside the MainActivity or Fragment

```
 recyclerView.setAdapter(new RecyclerView.Adapter() {
         @NonNull
         @Override
         public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
             return null;
         }

         @Override
         public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
         }

         @Override
         public int getItemCount() {
             return 0;
         }
     });

}
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
    }
}
```

Comment: if you want re-use  same `Adapter` class then  create  separate class for `Adapter`

Comment: Performance is not a factor here, but use 1 for readability / separation

Comment: First approach is a better approach for code readability and seperation of concerns where your Recylerview is independent of a view and you just pass data to it which will take care of populating data.                                           second approach is bad because we are giving too much information to MainActivity whose job is to just display data and the code is tightly coupled which becomes difficult for unit testing.

Comment: As a side note, the anonymous class in example 2 is complied to a class named MainActivity$1 (or the like) at compile-time. Thus there is virtually no difference in logic. The others are right though, example 1 should be preferred because it makes your code re-usable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The adapter should be implemented as a separated class, because it makes re-using it easier:

```
 public class YourAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.MyViewHolder> {

 private ArrayList<YourModel> list = new ArrayList();

public YourAdapter(ArrayList<YourModel> list){
 this.list = list;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    //return the viewholder
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder myViewHolder, int i) {
 //deal with data
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    //return the list number
}

class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
      //bind the views
    }
}
}
```

Than in your Activity/Fragment you can use it like this :

```
//after you have initialized recyclerview and added the layoutmanager
//prepare the list for the adapter
recyclerView.setAdapter(new YourAdapter(yourList));
```

This way you can reuse it in more than one Activity/Fragment. This pattern of reusable code should be preferred because you don't have to create the classes multiple times as anonymous classes - if needed.

Answer (score -1):

the best way is to set adapter class outside main class as your explain just use your first class

Comment: why is that the best way?

Comment: you just need to learn more about Design Pattern to design your code in best way